# target_link_libraries() cannot specify link libraries for target?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

Why am I getting this error/how do I fix it?

```
$ cmake -B build -S source 
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "venus" which is not built by this
  project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/user/Projects/Venus/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/user/Projects/Venus/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I did a `brew install` on GLFW and GLEW.

Layout:

```
.
├── build
└── source
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

`source/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.2)

project(venus)

# GLFW
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(venus glfw)

# OPENGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(venus OpenGL::GL)

add_executable(venus main.cpp)
```

`source/main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Starting Up Venus..." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use GLEW why the `find_package(OpenGL)`?

Answer (score 2):

`target_link_libraries()` goes [*after*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/command/target_link_libraries.html) `add_executable()` (emphasis mine):

> This command has several signatures as detailed in subsections below. All of them have the general form
>
> ```
> target_link_libraries(<target> ... <item>... ...)
> ```
>
> **The named `<target>` must have been created by a command such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()`** and must not be an ALIAS target. ...

Reordered:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.2)
project(venus)

# GLFW
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)

# OPENGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_executable(venus main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(venus glfw)
target_link_libraries(venus OpenGL::GL)
```